# Rails 4 - ActionMailer Send Shipping Confirmation Email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I'm building a marketplace app where sellers can list items to sell. I've set up ActionMailer to send out an order confirmation email which is triggered on `order.save`. I'm now trying to set up a shipping confirmation email, which will be triggered when the seller clicks on a button to indicate the item has been shipped.

I'm getting stuck on the data being passed through to the ActionMailer. I get an `undefined method 'buyer'` error on `@order.buyer.email` in the mailer method below. How do I pass buyer info to the mailer?

I'd also like to pass listing data to the mailer so I can use listing details in the email content.

Model info: I have a User model, a Listing model and an Order model. The order model has a buyer_id column which is a foreign key to the User model and a listing_id which is a foriegn key to the listing model. The users email is stored in the User model.

Here is my code:

```
#route
get 'shipconf' => "orders#shipconf"

#order_controller
def shipconf
  AutoNotifier.shipconf_email(@order).deliver
end

#AutoNotifier.rb
def shipconf_email(order)
   @order =  order
   mail(to: @order.buyer.email, bcc: "ashfaaqmoosa@gmail.com", subject: 'You have a new order at Outfit Additions.')
end

#sellers admin view table with order info. seller clicks button to send mail.
  <% @orders.each do |order| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= order.id %></td>
      <td><%= link_to order.listing.name.downcase.titleize, order.listing, data: { no_turbolink: true } %></td>
      <td><%= number_to_currency(order.listing.price) %></td>
      <td><%= order.shipaddress %></td>
      <td><%= best_in_place order, :tracking, :type => :input, :url => listing_order_path(id: order.id, listing_id: order.listing_id) %> </td>
      <td><%= link_to "Send Email", shipconf_path(order), class: "btn btn-sm btn-primary" %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>

#order model
belongs_to :listing
belongs_to :buyer, class_name: "User"
belongs_to :seller, class_name: "User"

#user model
has_many :listings, dependent: :destroy
has_many :orders, class_name: "Order", foreign_key: "seller_id"
has_many :purchases, class_name: "Order", foreign_key: "buyer_id"

#listing model
belongs_to :user
has_many :orders
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you define the `@order` variable somewhere for your shipconf action?

If not you have to define it, for example like this:

```
#order_controller
def shipconf
  @order = Order.find(params[:id])
  AutoNotifier.shipconf_email(@order).deliver
end
```

And change your link to:

```
shipconf_path(id: order.id)
```

Comment: In my button, I pass the order to the method `shipconf_path(order)`. Isn't that sufficient? I tried your suggestion but I get an error saying `could not find order without an ID`

Comment: No, it's not sufficient! You pass the order or the order_id inside your link so that you can search for it in the action. Try `Order.find(params[:order_id])`

Comment: Just so I understand, what was wrong with passing (order). I thought that would pass the entire order record including the id.